# GAPI google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How can I get my events data from GA using gapi?

I have some sample code that retrieves "source" and "visits".
I want my events from a category called "Videos" with action called "Play", each having the file name as the label.

Here is my current working code for plain visits:

```
<?php
require 'gapi-1.3/gapi.class.php';

/* Set your Google Analytics credentials */
define('ga_account'     ,'dadadadad');
define('ga_password'    ,'adadadad');
define('ga_profile_id'  ,'dadadadad');

$ga = new gapi(ga_account,ga_password);

/* We are using the 'source' dimension and the 'visits' metrics */
$dimensions = array('source');
$metrics    = array('visits');

/* We will sort the result be desending order of visits,
 and hence the '-' sign before the 'visits' string */
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, $dimensions, $metrics,'-visits');

$gaResults = $ga->getResults();

$i=1;

foreach($gaResults as $result)
{
    printf("%-4d %-40s %5d\n",
    $i++,
    $result->getSource(),
    $result->getVisits());
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo "\n-----------------------------------------\n";
echo "Total Results : {$ga->getTotalResults()}";



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to surmise what the function names would be.
This is working for me:

```
$ga = new gapi(ga_account,ga_password);

/* We are using the 'source' dimension and the 'visits' metrics */
$dimensions = array('eventLabel');
//$metrics    = array('totalEvents','uniqueEvents','eventsPerVisitWithEvent');
$metrics    = array('totalEvents');
$sort_metric = '-totalEvents';
/* We will sort the result be desending order of visits,
 and hence the '-' sign before the 'visits' string */
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, $dimensions, $metrics,'-totalEvents');

$gaResults = $ga->getResults();

$i=1;

foreach($gaResults as $result)
{
    printf("%-4d %-40s %5d\n",
    $i++,
    $result->getEventLabel(),
    $result->getTotalEvents()/*,
    //$result->getUniqueEvents(),
    //$result->getEventsPerVisitWithEvent() */);
    echo '<br/>';
}

echo "\n-----------------------------------------\n";
echo "Total Results : {$ga->getTotalResults()}";
```